# White Noise Space and Local Time

Tags: stochastic-processes

This question follows from the answer I gave to the question ["Wiener Meets Sobolev"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88183/sobolev-meets-wiener).

I was wondering in the context of White Noise Space if the Local Time at $x$ of a pre-Brownian motion is a notion that can be properly defined.

Best regards.

*Edit:* 
I have found a paper by Nualart and Vives "Chaos Expansions and Local Times" that allows to expand the local time into a Wiener Chaos expansion, but I cannot yet connect the dots to make it live into the White noise space. Any help appreciated.

[Here](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/PUBLICACIONSMATEMATIQUES_1992_36_2B_07.pdf) is a link to the Nualart and Vives paper.